# Perform actions as promises get fulfilled using Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-6

I can asynchronously resolve a bunch of promises with `Promise.all(array)`. However `.then()` will run only after all those promises have been resolved. How I can perform actions as the promises get resolved?

For example, I want to load all paragraphs from an article asynchronously using `Promise.all()` - This way the network requests all fire at once. If paragraph 1 is done loading, I want it to render to the page - but only if it is done loading before paragraph 2, then I want paragraph 2 to load. If paragraph 3 is done loading and 2 is not, I want 3 to wait for 2 before rendering to the page. And so on.

I tried something like this but I don't know what to do next:

```
var getStuff = function(number, time){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    window.setTimeout(function(){resolve(`${number} - Done.`)}, time);
  });
};

Promise.all([ getStuff(1, 200),
              getStuff(2, 100),
              getStuff(3, 250),
              getStuff(4, 200),
              getStuff(5, 300),
              getStuff(6, 250),
              getStuff(7, 5000)])
.then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

How can I get the console log of the data to happen one after another - without resolving each promise with a `then()` before making the next request? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Some promise libraries have *progress* callbacks.

Comment: There's no way to get that behaviour using native es6? Without adding another library to my project?

Comment: Why not just `getStuff(...)` and `then` render, for each promise?

Comment: I don't think it's available natively. You could still have an array of your promises though, and have an individual `then()` on each one.

Comment: If you want to "waterfall" the promises, so one finishes before another etc. it sounds like what you want is exactly multiple `then()` calls that returns another promise etc.

Comment: My main point is to not do a bunch of .then calls because if I am just waiting for each promise to resolve then essentially I'm just doing synchronous calls.. I'd like to get the best of both worlds where I can make the network requests at once asynchronously but do things as those requests are done.

Comment: No you're not doing synchronous calls, you're doing asynchronous calls in order, there's a difference.

Comment: Ahh, apologies, you are correct. But it essentially emulates synchronous calls, which is what I'm trying to work around.

Comment: `Promise.all([ getStuff(1, 200).then(logIt),
              getStuff(2, 100).then(logIt),
              getStuff(3, 250).then(logIt),
              getStuff(4, 200).then(logIt),, ...])` or an equivalent without the copy-pasting.

Comment: @immibis that won't actually do what was asked. What this code does is creates a `then` handler for each promise individually, so each request will be logged when its finished but does nothing to ensure a correct reaction order where `stuff(X)` should get logged only if `stuff(X-1)` already got logged.

Comment: @nem035 Oh, I missed that part.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot achieve this order using `Promise.all` because the promise returned from `Promise.all` waits for all promises from the provided array to resolve concurrently (as opposed to sequentially) before it itself resolves.

Instead, you can individually create the promises and fire of their requests concurrently:

```
// create promises and make concurrent requests
const s1 = getStuff(1, 200);
const s2 = getStuff(2, 100);
const s3 = getStuff(3, 250);
// ...
```

Then create a reaction chain on how to process them (stuff1 before stuff2, stuff2 before stuff3, etc.)

```
// create a chain of reaction order to the results of parallel promises
s1
  .then(console.log) // s1 resolved: log result
  .then(() => s2)    // chain s2
  .then(console.log) // s2 resolved: log result
  .then(() => s3)    // chain s3
  // ...
  .then(() => {      // chain another function at at the end for when all promises resolved
    // all promises resolved (all data was logged)
  }
```

---

To react to promise results in the same order the promises were created, you can change your `getStuff` function to dynamically chain the reactions using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var times = [200, 100, 250, 200, 300, 250, 5000];

var getStuff = function(time, index) { // swap the order of arguments so number is the index passed in from Array.map
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`${index + 1} - Done.`); // use index + 1 because indexes start at 0
    }, time);
  });
};

times
  // map each time to a promise (and number to the index of that time + 1) and fire of a request
  .map(getStuff)
  // dynamically build a reaction chain for the results of promises
  .reduce((chain, promise) => {
    return chain
      .then(() => promise)
      .then(console.log);
  }, Promise.resolve())
  .then(() => {
    // all promises resolved (all data was logged in order)
  });
```

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense! Basically, as soon as I call the getStuff's, they'll be making the network requests and if do the then chains after, I will be getting the behaviour I want because each promise will be resolved before the .then is called in the chain?

Comment: As soon as you create a Promise it will run your request. You can build the chain at any point after that, regardless if the promise resolved or not by that point. If the promise resolved before you made the chain it will just hold its value until you make the chain. If you make the chain first, the chain will wait for the promise to receive the value. That is the beauty of promises. They always resolves asynchronously and you can always pretend as if you already have the values when coding with them.

Answer (score 6):

nem035's answer is spot on. I want to point out that typically in this case you want to take *the same* action when requests happen and another action when they're all done.

You can use `.all` for that with `.map`:

```
Promise.all([ getStuff(1, 200),
            getStuff(2, 100),
            getStuff(3, 250),
            getStuff(4, 200),
            getStuff(5, 300),
            getStuff(6, 250),
            getStuff(7, 5000)]
.map(request => request.then(v => {
   console.log("Request done! Got," v); // or some action per request
   return v;
})).then(data => console.log(data));
```

You can boss this further with `.map` by using the fact you're using the same function for every request:

```
Promise.all([[1, 200],
            [2, 100],
            [3, 250],
            [4, 200],
            [5, 300],
            [6, 250],
            [7, 5000]])
.map((a, b) => getStuff(a, b))
.map(request => request.then(v => {
   console.log("Request done! Got," v); // or some action per request
   return v;
})).then(data => console.log(data));
```

And further to:

```
Promise.all([200, 100, 250, 200, 300, 250, 5000])
.map((a, i) => getStuff(a, i + 1))
.map(request => request.then(v => {
   console.log("Request done! Got," v); // or some action per request
   return v;
})).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Or with bluebird:

```
const sideEffect = v => console.log("Got partial result", v));
const data = [200, 100, 250, 200, 300, 250, 5000];
Promise.map(data, (a, i) => getStuff(a, i + 1).tap(sideEffect))
       .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Of course - you should just fix your backend, it's entirely unreasonable to ask the client to make 7 requests for different parts of the data - have the backend take ranges.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not native, but with bluebird you can use `Promise.some` (to fullfill after `count` promises have been fulfilled) or `Promise.mapSeries` (to fullfill promises in series) to somehow achieve the flow you expect.

[Bluebird API](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Normal operation:** You can use `Promise.all()` safely. The promise executers will be fired in parallel and the results will be returned in the order you insert your promises into the promises array. Then it's up to you to sort them the way you like. Such as in the following snippet we have five promises each will resolve randomly within 5 seconds. Regardless their resolution time you will get the results when the latest resolves;

```js
var promises = [ new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("1st paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
                 new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("2nd paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
                 new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("3rd paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
                 new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("4th paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
                 new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("5th paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
               ];
Promise.all(promises)
       .then(result => console.log(result.reduce((p,c) => p + "\n" + c)));
```

**What you want:** But then you don't want to wait as long as the last one finishes but instead want to process them in the order, ASAP they get resolved. Then `Array.prototype.reduce()` is your best friend here. Such as

```js
var promises = [ new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("1st paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
                 new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("2nd paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
                 new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("3rd paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
                 new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("4th paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000))),
                 new Promise( v => setTimeout(_ => v("5th paragraph text"),~~(Math.random()*5000)))
               ];
promises.reduce((p,c) => p.then(result => (console.log(result + "\n"),c)))
        .then(result => (console.log(result + "\n")));
```

Please run the code several times to see how the code behaves. The text will be updated ASAP the promise resolves but only if it is it's turn. So if 1st resolves after 2nd we will see 1st and 2nd to appear at once in their order but they will not wait for the 3rd to resolve an so on...